# Как вместо нескольких дефисов сделать один?

Tags: php

Как из текста **ssilka-na---top** сделать чтобы был максимум один дефис **ssilka-na-top**

Нужно **---** искать в строке, и заменять на **-**. Или есть способ проще?

Comment: `preg_replace( '/\-{2,}/','-', $str );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$mystring = 'ssilka-na---top';
echo preg_replace( '/--+/','-', $mystring );
```

Answer (score 1):

Заменять 2 и более дефиса на один, например с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
$ php -r "var_dump(preg_replace('/\-+/', '-', 'ssilka-na---top'));"
string(13) "ssilka-na-top"
```

Comment: сорри) @zenden2k был первый